# How to return a custom response inside the ExceptionLogger

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Inside the Log method there is no context.Response = MyResponse;

How can I return a custom response like:

When my Log method is called i want to pass the id to the current request. The problem is how can I get the content instance of the Request, to pass it the id?

Thats the action causing the exception:

```
   public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetConfiguredProducts(int number)
    {
        var products = await service.Get(number);
        return Ok(products);
    }


public class GlobalExceptionLogger : ExceptionLogger
    {
        private static int id;

        public override void Log(ExceptionLoggerContext context)
        {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref id);
            loggingService.ErrorException(string.Format("id: {0}", id), context.Exception);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show example how you call this?

Comment: I wrote the full action method above which is called as an example.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. There *is no response* to log - ExceptionLogger only logs *unhandled* exceptions. This means your code crashed before it was able to generate and send a response. The request though is available through the [ExceptionLoggerContext.Request](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.exceptionhandling.exceptionloggercontext.request(v=vs.118).aspx#P:System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionLoggerContext.Request) property.

Comment: Thats true now where you say it. No response available when exception. Thus I passed the logging id via response header now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a System.Web based stack (it's probably the case if you're using IIS and ASP.NET version < 5), you can get a reference to the request and response anywhere using the

```
HttpContext.Current
```

object.

Answer (score 0):

ExceptionLoggerContext exposes ExceptionContext which exposes Request and RequestContext. Will it be enough?

Comment: I have seen them... but how do you take the return value from the called action add an id to a property from the return value and forwared this whole object then to the client?

Comment: If you handle exception it means something wrong happened and this you should take an action. What is the point to adding anything to request? Request is something what comes from browser and processing this request exception was thrown then you should take an action - clean what happened wrong and redirect to another page - apologize page for example.

Comment: // When an exception occurs there is of course no response, thus I can not add any data to the response object. I added it now to the response header.
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("LoggingId", id.ToString());